# app is not defined after bundling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, browserify

I am running browserify on my code, it is as follows:

```
import './app';

//——————————————————————————————————————————————————//
// Components
//——————————————————————————————————————————————————//

import './components/_ntToggleClass';
```

app is simply

```
const app = angular.module('app', []);
```

while files in `components` are, well, components. But they are using forementioned `app`:

```
  app.directive('ntToggleClass', () => {
    ...    }
```

When I put everything in one file by hand, all worked. But after I used browserify on this, I am getting

> Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined

When I look inside the code, both `var app` and the directive are there.

Comment: This doesn't help, sorry.

Comment: Try using `require("./components/_ntToggleClass.js")`, which should directly copy the contents of the file.

Comment: Also doesn't work, @ScottKaye

Comment: see my updated answer, where I posted a link to a quick demo I slapped together and posted on github. @ScottKaye was correct BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine came with help ;-)

I am using Babel (I thought thas was obvious, since I used `import` not `require`) for my coding (Babelify with `es2015`, to be precise), so, as I have `import`, I need `export` too.

Solution is very simple, all I had to do is to put

```
export default app;
```

at the end of my `app.js` file and then import it using

```
import app from '../app';
```

into my directives/components etc.

Comment: I am using require instead of import and facing the same problem, I bundled two controllers into a single file and on bundled second file it gives app is not defined  @Tomek

Answer (score 1):

I've slapped together a quick sample on [github](https://github.com/pjetr/browserify-demo). This will give you a working repository that runs browserify.

I've removed my previous comments, as I think the repo should answer your questions.

*edit:* I think I just now got your question, you were trying to create a global variable `app` to just be used in each other file?
This is impossible when using browserify, any variable that isn't `required` in your file will be returning `undefined`.

When using browserify, just require whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about definition ordering.

`const app = angular.module('app', []);` 
This part should be top of below part:

```
app.directive('ntToggleClass', () => {
    ...    }
```

Comment: While this works, I would prefer to avoid writing `const app...` in every file.